# Calligraphic fonts for chapters,

Tags: fonts, calligraphy

I'm currently using calligraphic font and it works fine with 1 exception: Chapter/Section and title aren't affected by it. How can it be made that they too can be affected (and if its a general way how can it be done that the title is not affected but chapters and sections)?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,BCOR10mm,DIV11,toc=listof,parskip=full, openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace{0pt}}
\renewcommand{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace{\baselineskip}}
\patchcmd{\section}{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{-\z@}{}{} 
\patchcmd{\section}{2.3ex \@plus .2ex}{1sp}{}{} 
\patchcmd{\subsection}{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{-\z@}{}{}
\patchcmd{\subsection}{1.5ex \@plus .2ex}{1sp}{}{}
\patchcmd{\subsubsection}{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{-\z@}{}{}
\patchcmd{\subsubsection}{1.5ex \@plus .2ex}{1sp}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@xsect}{\ignorespaces}{\vspace*{-.5\baselineskip}\ignorespaces}{}{}


\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{\if@twoside\next@tpage}{\iffalse}{}{}

\makeatother

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}            
\usepackage{multicol}            
\usepackage[usenames,svgnames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx,eso-pic}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}

\newenvironment{calligraphic}%
{\usefont{T1}{pzc}{m}{it}}%
{}%

\begin{document}
\begin{calligraphic}
\maktetitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{test1}
mytesttext
\end{calligraphic}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because [KOMA-script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) issues a separate font selection to set chapter titles. Specifically, `\sectfont`, which defaults to

```
\newcommand*{\sectfont}{\normalcolor\sffamily\bfseries}
```

Changing this to

```
\renewcommand*{\sectfont}{\normalcolor\usefont{T1}{pzc}{m}{it}}
```

produces the desired output:

[image]